# Getting error while creating sencha extjs project in windows 7

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Find the below steps and error which is occuring while creating a extjs project in windows 7.

Error:

Below is the command which i am entering in windows cmd. I am trying to install the project in E:\workspace. But its creating some folder in the name but throws error.

```
C:\Users\Testing_Valleycrest>sencha -sdk E:\extjs generate app account_manager E
:\workspace\test
Sencha Cmd v3.1.2.342
[INF]
[INF] init-plugin:
[INF]
[INF] -before-generate-workspace:
[INF]
[INF] cmd-root-plugin.init-properties:
[INF]
[INF] init-properties:
[INF]
[INF] init-sencha-command:
[INF]
[INF] init:
[INF]
[INF] generate-workspace-impl:
[INF]      [echo] generating into E:\workspace\test from C:\Users\Testing_Valley
crest\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.1.2.342/templates/workspace
[INF]     [mkdir] Created dir: E:\workspace\test\packages
[INF]
[INF] cmd-root-plugin.copy-framework-to-workspace-impl:
[INF] [propertyfile] Updating property file: E:\workspace\test\.sencha\workspace
\sencha.cfg
[INF]
[INF] copy-framework-to-workspace-impl:
[INF]      [copy] Copying 4522 files to E:\workspace\test\ext
[INF]      [copy] Copying 89 files to E:\workspace\test\ext\src\ux
[INF] [propertyfile] Updating property file: E:\workspace\test\.sencha\workspace
\sencha.cfg
[INF]
[INF] copy-framework-to-workspace:
[INF]
[INF] generate-workspace:
[INF]
[INF] -after-generate-workspace:
[INF]
[INF] init-plugin:
[INF]
[INF] cmd-root-plugin.init-properties: 
[INF]
[INF] init-properties:
[INF]
[INF] init-sencha-command: 
[INF]
[INF] init:
[INF]
[INF] before-upgrade:
[INF]
[INF] generate-app-impl:
[INF]
[INF] generate-starter-app:
[INF]     [mkdir] Created dir: E:\workspace\test\resources
[INF]     [mkdir] Created dir: E:\workspace\test\overrides
[INF]     [mkdir] Created dir: E:\workspace\test\sass\src
[INF]     [mkdir] Created dir: E:\workspace\test\sass\var
[INF]     [mkdir] Created dir: E:\workspace\test\sass\etc
[INF] [x-property-file] Updating property file: E:\workspace\test\.sencha\app\se
ncha.cfg
[INF]
[INF] after-upgrade:
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 1 second
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException.
```

Comment: I see you're using Sencha Cmd 3.1.2 -- what version of Ext JS are you using?

Comment: The point at where it is failing is where it includes and generates the theme for the default app. You sure you have the full extjs source unzipped to E:\extjs?

Comment: @arthurakay - I am using extjs4

Comment: @bakamike - I am having full extjs extracted inside the E:\extjs folder anyway i will check again.

Comment: If I were you, I would download a fresh copy of Ext JS (4.2.x) and run "sencha upgrade" to ensure you're using the latest versions of both parts. Then try again.